# How to disable the plus sign next to the line number that allows me to comment on the code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I activated this feature but don't know how. When I move my mouse to the left side for each line of code, I'm getting a "+" sign and when I click the plus sign, I can comment on the code.

[image: image showing the plus sign on the left of code]

How can I activate/deactivate this? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: In case the accepted answer doesn't work, also try `"comments.visible": false,` in the settings.json. It could be from other extensions too such as CodyAI. Hopefully, adding the mentioned setting will disable it altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is suppose to be apart of reviewing pull requests I believe as part of the [GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github).  As you said, that allows you to add comments, which should be captured on the pull request after doing so.  The extension page even has a .gif showing how the comment feature works (the .gif is somewhat outdated though, as its not a "+" sign in the .gif).  Here is how it looks on a pull request:

[image: plus sign on pull request for adding comments]

You could disable this extension, but really you should only be seeing this if you are reviewing a pull request I believe (is that what you are doing?).  That, or maybe a GitHub issue too (I'm not sure how those work since I/my team don't use GitHub issues).

Comment: I don’t review any pull request

Answer (score 0):

Disable better comments plugin.
[image]